# PHP cURL Error Calling By Web URL

Tags: php

I got the following PHP code:

```
    $webUrl = WEB_URL_CONSTANT;
    $webUrl = str_replace('%op%', $operator, $webUrl);
    $webUrl = str_replace('%subno%', $msisdn, $webUrl);

    echo $webUrl;

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $webUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $xml = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $xml;
```

The $xml variable return empty, but if I replace the $webUrl on the following line with the direct link to the URL then I get valid values back:

```
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://....");
```

Why? How can I fix?

Thanks

Comment: Well, what does `WEB_URL_CONSTANT` contain?

Comment: That contain the URL to the page...

Comment: is the output of echo $webUrl; and the direct link "http:\\...." same?

Comment: Yes the are the same besides those variables that get replaced.

Comment: `http:\\ ` is invalid (should be `http://`), and I very much doubt `$webUrl` is containing exactly the same URL as the succeeding test, as that would be logically impossible. So, enlighten us with the exact (differences in) url. Never `echo` while debugging, but `var_dump` your variables, and check them in the _source_ of a webpage (to avoid missing HTML tags / whitespace / other entities).

Comment: I double checked and both $webUrl and the hard coded URL have the exact same URL.

Answer (score 0):

The page redirect to another URL that return the  XML....
So I first called the first page that do the redirect, grab the URL, call that URL and finally got the XML.... :-)